# can any one help me to solve the following jvm crash

Tags: java, swing, jvm

Trying to execute the following code

```
javax.swing.JFileChooser chooser = new javax.swing.JFileChooser();
chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("."));
```

The JVM crashed with the following error log

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x742f565e, pid=9332, tid=1516
# JRE version: 7.0-b147
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (21.0-b17 mixed mode windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [windows.storage.dll+0x12565e]
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows

Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [windows.storage.dll+0x12565e]  STORAGE_SHGetDesktopFolderWorker+0x19e
C  [windows.storage.dll+0x1254f2]  STORAGE_SHGetDesktopFolderWorker+0x32
C  [awt.dll+0xada27]  Java_sun_awt_shell_Win32ShellFolder2_initDesktop+0xf
j  sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolder2.initDesktop()V+0
j  sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolder2.access$100(Lsun/awt/shell/Win32ShellFolder2;)V+1
j  sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolder2$1.call()Ljava/lang/Void;+11
j  sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolder2$1.call()Ljava/lang/Object;+1
Heap
 def new generation   total 15680K, used 5440K [0x054d0000, 0x065d0000, 0x0aa20000)
  eden space 13952K,  26% used [0x054d0000, 0x058702b8, 0x06270000)
  from space 1728K, 100% used [0x06420000, 0x065d0000, 0x065d0000)
  to   space 1728K,   0% used [0x06270000, 0x06270000, 0x06420000)
 tenured generation   total 34768K, used 25965K [0x0aa20000, 0x0cc14000, 0x154d0000)
   the space 34768K,  74% used [0x0aa20000, 0x0c37b6c8, 0x0c37b800, 0x0cc14000)
 compacting perm gen  total 14592K, used 14362K [0x154d0000, 0x16310000, 0x194d0000)
   the space 14592K,  98% used [0x154d0000, 0x162d6bd0, 0x162d6c00, 0x16310000)
No shared spaces configured.

Dynamic libraries:
0x00c90000 - 0x00cbf000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe
0x76e80000 - 0x77023000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
0x74d30000 - 0x74e20000     C:\Windows\System32\KERNEL32.DLL
0x76960000 - 0x76b74000     C:\Windows\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
VM Arguments:
java_command: E:\Install-G\GCalc21.02.01 - Copy\GCALC_MAIN21.02.01.jar
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD
```

Comment: I doubt that anyone can help here. The best move is to deinstall that ancient Java and install a newer version. However, Webstart support has been dropped with JDK 11, so the latest version with long term support is Java 8.

Comment: `JRE version: 7.0-b147` <- JDK 16 has been released recently, but you are still using an unsupported ten years old JRE.

Comment: i use msaccess as my database so i can`t update to newer version of java

Comment: How does the database relate to the Java version?

Answer (score 0):

Try:
[1]: https://ugetfix.com/ask/how-to-fix-exception-access-violation-error-on-windows-10/

An access violation essentially means something tried to access protected data. Apart from the suggestions in the link above, also consider:

- Escalating your application's access by running it "As Administrator"
- Look at the task manager when you run your program and see if any scanners/programs you have running spin up in cycles, potentially implicating them as the cause. Some virus/malweare scanners are notorious for putting file locks on things they're scanning that can impair access to those filesystem resources by other applications.